# Multivariable Delta Epsilon Proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove the following limits using the delta-epsilon method. Can you help me out?

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}(x+y) = a+b$$

Comment: You want to prove that
$$\forall (a,b)\in \Bbb R^2\forall \delta>0 \exists \varepsilon >0\forall(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2\left(|(x,y)-(a,b)|<\varepsilon\implies |(x+y)-(a-b)|<\delta\right).$$

Let $(a,b)\in \Bbb R^2$ and $\delta >0$ be taken arbitrarily.

I only checked in my head, but $\varepsilon =\dfrac \delta 2$ seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:
Since on $\mathbb R^n$ all norms are equivalent, chose the easiest: $\Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty$. This will leave you with two 1-D. $\epsilon$-$\delta$ arguments where
$$\epsilon = (\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)$$
and you want
$$|x+y-a-b| = |(x-a)+(y-b)| \leq |x-a| + |y-b| < \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 = 2\Vert\epsilon\Vert_\infty$$
Get the gist? I can provide more detail if needed.

---

Now all that remains to prove is
$$\lim_{x\to a} x = a$$
or equivalently (by exchanging symbols)
$$\lim_{y\to b} y = b$$
For the choice of $\delta$, $\delta_\epsilon := \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ suits your needs.

---

**Proof**
Using equivalency of norms on $\mathbb R^n$, we have to prove
$$\forall\ \epsilon > 0 \quad \exists\ \delta > 0$$
such that
$$|x+y - (a+b)| < \epsilon \qquad \forall\ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | \Vert (x,y) - (a,b) \Vert_\infty < \delta$$
Now for $\delta := \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ we have
$$|x+y - (a+b)| \leq |x-a| + |y-b| < \delta + \delta = 2\delta = \epsilon$$
q.e.d.

---

**Note**
Using the euclidean norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_2$ we can chose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{4}$, since
$$\Vert (x,y) \Vert_2^2 = x^2 + y^2 \leq x^2 + 2|x||y| + y^2 = (|x| + |y|)^2 \leq (2\Vert(x,y)\Vert_\infty)^2$$
(actually we give away a bit here, but that's not important for the task at hand)

Comment: Thank you! I don't really understand what you chose for delta. What is this dot? I am sorry, I am still learning the basics! Also, What do you mean that this leaves us with two 1-D. ε-δ arguments?

Comment: $\cdot$ is used as a placeholder, and with 1-D. I mean one-dimensional. For the concrete stuff, see the edit

Comment: @user92821 Any questions remaining? If not I suggest you mark the question as answered.

Comment: You can still use $\Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty$, but I guess a different choice of $\delta$ is needed ;-). Essentially that means yes, you can. // Besides you have shown in the original problem, that you can take the limits per summand and add up afterwards.

Comment: Okay! Thanks so much AlexR.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: For $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \epsilon / 2$. Then show that if $|x-a|  < \delta$ and $|y-b| < \delta$, then $|(x+y) - (a+b)| < \epsilon$. This should suffice for whatever choice of metric you want to use on ${\mathbb R}^2$, getting the point across without particulars about choice of metric etc. Intuitively it just shows that as $(x,y)$ gets close to $(a,b)$, you get that $x+y$ gets close to $a+b$.

Comment: This proof implicitly uses the $\infty$-metric...

Comment: I agree, but the question is whether they're even considering explicit different metrics in limit problems. My guess is that the $\infty$-metric is the canonical one for simple problems like this. It also is the metric that appeals the most to intuition, i.e. choosing one $\delta$ for all variables.

Comment: It sure does and the equivalency of norms assures us the correct result independent of the norm, but essentially this is no different than the proof I stated, only a tad bit less exact.
Referring to @GitGud, we should probably find a way around this (i.e. using the euclidean norm).

Comment: Ideally a well-posed limit problem should either state a norm or state that we can assume all norms are equivalent. I agree your answer subsumes mine, I was just trying to side-step the quagmire of different norms by appealing to the most intuitive one, and making a side-comment that it should be intuitively obvious that this $\infty$-norm is sufficient for any other one.

Comment: I agree on this point, the norm should have been mentioned in the problem or the lecture. To clarify the equivalence of at least the two most common norms, $\Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty$ and $\Vert\cdot\Vert_2$, I added a note to my answer.